# Installing system update bricked an unrooted LG K7

Tags: updates, unbricking

I have an unrooted LG K7 metroPCS phone running Android 5.1.1.  Earlier today a notification popped up that a system update with security patches was available.  I clicked "Download and Install", and the usual "Installing System Update" animation displayed for a few minutes, after which the phone restarted.

But on restart the phone gets stuck at the splash screen, and will not get past it.  I know I can do a hard factory reset and start all over but I'd really prefer not to.  Any suggestions on

- Why this happened?
- What I can do about it?

For what it's worth, I use a Mac, so any suggestions that require using a PC to access root functionality are probably non-starters.

**Edited:**  It's worse than I thought.  I got impatient and decided to do a hard factory reset anyway, but after that it is *still* getting stuck on the splash screen.  Help!

**Edit 2:** And when I say "stuck at the splash screen", I mean *stuck*.  I have to remove the battery just to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own problem, so am posting the resolution here for the benefit of future searchers who might be encountering the same or similar situation.

Most online guides to un-bricking a phone are written with the assumption that the phone in question is rooted, and the recommended solutions all proceed from that assumption.  My phone was *not* rooted, and most of the suggestions -- putting the phone into download mode, flashing a new ROM, etc. -- were beyond my skill-set (basically a complete novice).

However, one online guide (specifically, [this one](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-k7/how-to/stock-firmware-rom-unbrick-lg-k7-k330-t-t3432878)) included a piece of information that I didn't find elsewhere: namely,

> Unbrick using LG Bridge (Mac & Windows)
>
> (If there is no KDZ available for your model or LG UP failed, try this)
>
> (Official way to unbrick. If it fails, blame LG)
>
> - Download LG Bridge from [here](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product-help/CT10000026-1438110404543-preinstall-apps).
> - Install LG Bridge
> - Open LG Bridge
> - Connect device to computer and let LG Bridge install drivers
> - Go to the Software update tab
> - Click "Update error recovery" on bottom right
> - LG Bridge will download and flash the KDZ for you.

This turned out to be exactly what I needed.